# REVISIT: How to configure the default shell in msys2/mintty?

Tags: git, cmd, msys2, mintty

I have the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44536373/how-to-configure-the-default-shell-in-msys2-mintty) prior Stackoverflow post. I got helicoptered into this situation due to git for Windows, not MinGW or cygwin, so the answers in that post don't seem viable.

I would like to start mintty from a Windows cmd.exe prompt, but when I type mintty there, I get this dialog box:

[image]

I always want to use MSYS2, so how can I tell mintty to use that instead of always going through the dialog box? I've tried the various options from this [page](https://www.msys2.org/wiki/Launchers/) but again these all assume I'm using MinGW or cygwin, not acquiring mintty/MSYS from git. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried:

```
mintty -o MSYSTEM=MSYS
```

It did open immediately a MSYS2 bash.

[image: MSYS2 bash]

That works if Git and its Linux commands are in the PATH:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

Comment: That got real close! When I run it, this line appears above the mintty prompt: "bash: cut: command not found".  There word "cut" does not appear ~/.bashrc. Also, many Linux commands like "cat" and "type" are missing when started with -o vs. starting without operands and then clicking on MSYS2.

Comment: @cniggeler Yes, I have added the PATH I am using for this to work.

Comment: I'll try it, but ti clutters my Windows path. Would you know why the behavior is different running mintty and mintty -o... ?

Comment: @cniggeler It relies on Linux command that `mintty` alone will include in its execution path. If you bypass that (with `mintty -o`), you need to have the right path alreadt set, since mintty won't set it up for you. Test it out.

Comment: I added the directories you specified to .bashrc PATH instead of Windows' PATH. Working like a champ (except for the missing "cut" command, but not affecting anything). Thank you ! +1